# How to use Query Builder to make a relation in an array? Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-query-builder

I would like to make a relation with query builder... I have three tables, and I would like to join the tables for work with the function.. I'm working in a model.. not in a controller

This is my function

```
public function map($contactabilidad): array
{
    $relation = DB::table('tbl_lista_contactabilidad')
        ->join('tbl_equipo_postventaatcs', 'tbl_equipo_postventaatcs.id', '=', 'tbl_lista_contactabilidad.postventaatc_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tbl_equipo_postventaatcs.asesor_id')
        ->get();

    return [
        $contactabilidad->$relation->name,
        $contactabilidad->postventaatc_id,
        $contactabilidad->rif,
        $contactabilidad->razon_social,
        $contactabilidad->fecha_contacto,
        $contactabilidad->persona_contacto,
        $contactabilidad->correo_contacto,
        $contactabilidad->numero_contacto,
        $contactabilidad->celular_contacto,
        $contactabilidad->comentarios,
        $contactabilidad->contactado,
        $contactabilidad->respuesta->respuesta
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Query\Builder is best thought of as the primary tool used by Eloquent, but is, nontheless, a completely different package. Query\Builder's purpose is to decouple SQL syntax from the logic that feeds into it, whereas Eloquent's purpose is to decouple that logic from table structures and relationships. So only Eloquent supports Model and Relation classes, Query\Builder does not. And what you're asking for has to do with Relations, so in short, you're kind of barking up the wrong tree.

By the way, I'm differentiating 'Query\Builder' here because Eloquent also has its own wrapper for that class called `Eloquent\Builder` that shares most of the same syntax. For better or for worse, Eloquent attempts to allow the developer to interact with it in a way that's familiar; not having to track a new set of method names even if you've been seamlessly dropped out of Eloquent and into a Query\Builder object via a magic `__call` method. It also does something similar regarding Eloquent\Collections vs. Support\Collections. But that can make things very confusing at first, because you have to just kind of know what package you're talking to.

So, to answer your question...

- Build a Model class for each of your three tables
- Apply [relationship methods](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) to each one to pre-configure the model with an awareness of your foreign keys
- Call on them using [lazy or eager-loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Something else to note is that `with()` does *not* ask Eloquent to perform a `JOIN`. All it does is run the parent query, extract the key values from the result, run the child query using them in an `IN()` statement, and marrying the results together afterwards. That's what results in nested results. Speaking from experience, it's kind of a mess generating true JOIN statements off Model Relations and keeping the table aliases unique, so it makes sense this package just skips trying to do that (except with pivot tables on many-to-many relations). This also has the added benefit though, that your related tables don't need to live in the same database. A Query\Builder `join()` on the other hand, as you have there, would present all fields for all tables at the top-level.